# SharePoint Calculated Field Limitation?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

On a calculated field is there any limit on the number of conditions?  I have the following but it does not seem to be producing accurate results..

```
=IF(
  OR([funnel status]="Early Engagement (Active)",[funnel status]="Early Engagement (Non-Active)",[funnel status]="DRFP (Active)",[funnel status]="DRFP (Non-Active)",[funnel status]="Post Proposal Submission"),
  "active",
    IF(
      OR([funnel status]="DRFP Question",[funnel status]="RFI",[funnel status]="RFP",[funnel status]="BAFO",[funnel status]="Orals Prep",[funnel status]="Orals",[funnel status]="Quals",[funnel status]="ENs",[funnel status]="FRP",[funnel status]="Bridge",[funnel status]="Contract MOD",[funnel status]="unsolicited"),
      "live",
      ""
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your question about limits, the OR function has a [limit of 30 conditions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OR-function-9a2a1cca-696f-4d19-a959-3943babd076f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US), but that shouldn't be causing you a problem in this case.

Try switching your formula to this:

```
=IF(
  OR(EXACT([funnel status],"Early Engagement (Active)"),
     EXACT([funnel status],"Early Engagement (Non-Active)"),
     EXACT([funnel status],"DRFP (Active)"),
     EXACT([funnel status],"DRFP (Non-Active)"),
     EXACT([funnel status],"Post Proposal Submission")),
  "active",
  IF(
    OR(EXACT([funnel status],"DRFP Question"),
       EXACT([funnel status],"RFI"),
       EXACT([funnel status],"RFP"),
       EXACT([funnel status],"BAFO"),
       EXACT([funnel status],"Orals Prep"),
       EXACT([funnel status],"Orals"),
       EXACT([funnel status],"Quals"),
       EXACT([funnel status],"ENs"),
       EXACT([funnel status],"FRP"),
       EXACT([funnel status],"Bridge"),
       EXACT([funnel status],"Contract MOD"),
       EXACT([funnel status],"unsolicited")),
    "live",
    ""
  )
)
```